# Graphing Functions for intersections

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

Let's say $f(x) = g(y)$.
Then how would we solve this equation graphically?

What my understanding is that we plot $g(y)$ on the $x$ axis and $f(x)$ on the $y$ axis and the intersections to the $2$ graphs are the solutions, but I don't think this is correct.

Comment: You might try your method with some examples to see if it works for those. If it does try to generalize.

Comment: Example: $f(x)=x^2$ and $g(y)=2y$. Therefore $x^2=2y$ If we solve for y we just get a graph in a x,y coordinate system: $y=\frac{x^2}2$. This is a parabola.